# Were there grammatical disagreements in Latin?

Tags: grammarians

Latin has such a long history that at some point some native — or otherwise very fluent — speakers surely have disagreed about what is correct and grammatical Latin.
I would like to know if such disagreements have survived in literature.

Let me formulate the question more precisely.
(Partial answers or interesting observations about the topic are welcome as answers, though; I don't mean to discourage anyone from answering.)
What is the earliest written record of grammatical disagreement, like "This other author wrote that *plenus* comes with ablative but he is wrong since it should always come with a genitive attribute"?
Ideally I would like to see a situation where two grammarians disagree on some point and the later writer is aware of the disagreement.

Comment: Totally OT, but once I read there were such disagreements between local variants of 1st century Hebrew.

Comment: Legendum, "something to be read." became the title of various collections, Legenda "things to be read."  By 1200 this was commonly treated as a Feminine nominative singular, "a legend."

Comment: It's late (3/4C), but are you familiar with the [Appendix Probi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_Probi)?

Comment: @TKR, I had never heard of that, but that Wikipedia article was an interesting read. I suppose that counts as a written record of some kind of grammatical disagreement. That would make a nice answer, even if it doesn't hit the nail exactly on the head.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There were plenty of discussions, and a record of some them has survived.

## Pronunciation and orthography

We have really a lot of specimens of this, for example from Cicero, Catullus, Quintilian, Varro. Also consider that emperor Claudius tried to reform the alphabet – this must have definitely spurred many discussions between erudite people and grammarians.

Velius Longus (7.58 s. K.) says that "there's controversy about whether equus must be written with one or two *u*".

Augustin (Conf. 1.29) was ironic about the fact that at his time it was more important to pronounce *homines* according to grammar rules [i.e. with h voiced] than to love them according to the law of God.

Catullus (c. 84):

> Chommoda dicebat, si quando commoda vellet
>   dicere, et insidias Arrius hinsidias.
>   et tum mirifice sperabat se esse locutum,
>   cum quantum poterat dixerat hinsidias.

## Lexicon

At least indirectly, the Appendix Probi mentioned in comments. Also the fragmentary *Dubius sermo* of Pliny the Elder (which according to naturalis historia 1.228 was badly criticized by grammarians); this was not only about lexicon but also other aspects of language.

Cicero ([Fam. 16.17](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=LatinAugust2012&getid=1&query=Cic.%20Fam.%2016.17)) criticizes a solecism from Tiro (thanks @TheHonRose):

> I see what you are about: you want your letters also to be collected into books. But look here! You set up to be a standard of correctness in my writings—how came you to use such an unauthorized expression as "by faithfully devoting myself to my health"? How does fideliter come in there? The proper habitat of that word is in what refers to duty to others—though it often migrates to spheres not belonging to it. For instance: "learning," "house," "art,,' "land," can be called fidelis, granting, as Theophrastus holds, that the metaphor is not pushed too far.

## Syntax

Here too we have plenty; consider that there was even a major split among grammarians between analogists and anomalists. Quintilian (1.5.14) talks about the "*pexus pinguisque doctor*" (!) who dared refuse the irregular but commonly used *adsentior* (the "correct" form would be *adsentio*).

Cicero tells us that analogists wanted to abolish the genitive in -um for all 2nd declension nouns, while he and the other anomalists wished to preserve it in frequently used genitives like nummum, sestertium, triumvirum, deum. Similar positions about "-asse" for "-avisse".

## Datation

As for the first occurrence, you'll find them as early as the IV century BCE in Greece – for example the controversy between analogists and anomalists began in Greece and was later adapted to the Latin language.

Comment: Can you give more precise references and quote or summarize some examples? Examples (in addition to *assentio(r)*) of actual disagreements would make this answer great.

Comment: I added some more examples, but I don't have anything as spicy as assentior at hand... you should find something good in Quintilian, maybe also Gellius.

Comment: Just one example, but in this letter, Cicero criticises Tiro's (apparent)  use of *faithfully* (*fideliter*) - so, yes, there were disagreements. http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=LatinAugust2012&getid=1&query=Cic.%20Fam.%2016.17

Comment: @TheHonRose thank'you! I'll add it in the answer